# Show that $K(z,t) \equiv \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}{e^{i(z,\xi)}\dfrac{\cos {|\xi|t}}{|\xi|^2}d\xi} = K(0,0,|z|,t)$, $z \in \mathbb{R}^3$ in spherical system

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, spherical-coordinates

Show that $K(z,t) \equiv \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}{e^{i(z,\xi)}\dfrac{\cos {|\xi|t}}{|\xi|^2}d\xi} = K(0,0,|z|,t)$, $z \in \mathbb{R}^3$ when switched to spherical coordinates. According to my textbook this function depends only on $|z|$ and $t$. I don't see why. After switching to spherical coordinate system,instead of $e^{i(z,\xi)}$ now there is $e^{ir\cos{(\theta)}|z|}$ where $r=|\xi|$ according to the textbook. How is this? Any suggestions?

Comment: When $(-,-)$ is the usual dot product in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the angle $t$ between $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined so that $|(a,b)| = \|a\| \|b\| \cos(t)$. Does this help?  I expect that $e^{ir|z| \cos(\theta)}$ is intended in your formula and not e.g. $e^{ir \cos(\theta |z|)}$. (Here "$\theta$" may be a function that might not be what you would usually call "$\theta$," perhaps depending on how you label spherical coordinates)

Comment: @leslietownes ohh I haven't used that definition of dot product for so long that I had completely forgotten about it! Thank you!

Comment: @leslietownes yes I just added parenthesis for better clarity